# Other PCAP network software other than TCPREPLAY?

Tags: pcap, tcpreplay

I would like to find out if there are more other useful softwares with the same functions or more like TCPREPLAY which has the ability to "playback" PCAP files? Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about any program that uses the libpcap library can replay pcap files, assuming by "replay" you mean "re-use saved network traffic" rather than "put that traffic back on the network".

For example, `tcpdump`, `wireshark`, `ngrep`, `tcpflow`, and probably dozens of other similar programs can work off both *live* network traffic, and off *saved* network traffic that then gets replayed within the application.

If, on the other hand, you're looking at injecting the network traffic back onto the network, then your options are much more limited. There's `PReplay` for Windows, `tcpreplay` and `capedit` for Linux/UNIX, and then a bunch of specialized tools for replaying specific types of traffic, usually related to network intrusion (such as `aireplay` to aid in WEP cracking).

Comment: I like to add [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/) as another alternative to inject network traffic back onto the network (OSX, Linux, Windows).